# How can I work with datasource with Excel using groovy in Soapui Pro 4.5.0?

Tags: groovy, automation, soapui

I have worked with Datasource with Excel file in SoapUI Pro 4.5.0 tool. Its working fine while doing manually in SoapUI Pro 4.5.0 tool. But I need to execute this process through the script (Groovy). That means, getting input from excel and assign them to Datasource option.

Is it possible?

The following URL I have used in my sample.

http://www.webservicex.com/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1):

I would imagine that you can use JDBC.

Here is an Excel JDBC driver: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xlsql/

You will probably need to add the JAR to /bin/ext and call registerjdbcdriver: http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/tips-a-tricks.html#10-use-a-jdbc-driver-from-inside-a-groovy-script